# Visual Studio Community 2019 Save HTML and CSS Files While Debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

I recently re-installed my dev machine and Visual Studio is not behaving like it used to.  I must have missed an important setting.  I used to be able to modify the html or css files within my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app while debugging.  After I saved the files and refreshed my browser, the changes were present.  That is no longer the case, I'm losing so much time restarting my debugging sessions.  Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Since net core 3.0, you should install another nuget package called [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/) and then do some changes from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#runtime-compilation). Then try again to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Since your project is based on .Net Core 3.1, you should install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 3.1` into your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After I saved the files and refreshed my browser, the changes were
>   present. That is no longer the case, I'm losing so much time
>   restarting my debugging sessions. Anyone know what I'm missing?

The main issue is that since **.Net Core 3.0**, if you want to debug edited content in real time, you should install a nuget package called `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` and then do some extra changes manually.

Before **.Net Core 2.2**, there was no need to worry about this. So when you debug projects based on Net Core 3.0 or above, you can try  these:

**Solution**

1)  try to install a nuget package called [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/) into your project. And note that your project is based on .Net Core 3.1, so you should install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 3.1` version.

2) do some changes in your startup page. In my side, it is `Startup.cs` file and then add these in the `ConfigureServices` function.

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

More info you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#runtime-compilation).

Hope it could help you.

Comment: This was driving me crazy for literally 2 days.  Thank you!