# Add a new folder to a solution while debugging on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, configuration, visual-studio-2017, directory-structure

A dumb question.

Is it possible to configure VS2017 to allow adding new folders while running a solution on debug mode? I'm trying to organize multiple styles and scripts defined inside the views.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure VS2017 to allow adding new folders while
>   running a solution on debug mode? I'm trying to organize multiple
>   styles and scripts defined inside the views.

**For a framework project**, there is no such option to realize it to add new file into a project under debugging. And when the project is under debug, the files under the solution explorer and we cannot modify such as add a new folder in Solution Explorer.And you cannot add new item into it.

**For a core project**, you can add a folder in this new type of the project. After that, you can add existing new item and import new files into it. As far as l know, it can work for showing the style of the page and you can modify it and then refresh the page,you will see the effect.

Note: if your project is based on Net Core 3.0 and later, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444770/visual-studio-community-2019-save-html-and-css-files-while-debugging/59450985#59450985) to install a new nuget package called Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: I'm on Net framework. Thank you for the info, it's to know than you can do it on Core.